# How to put a circuit breaker outside, after the outlet?

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

Suppose that I have an outside outlet running to a 20amp fuse in the circuit breaker.

Could I add a second fusebox physically plugged into the outdoor outlet?

A 25amp fuse would basically do nothing, right, as it would trip the 20 amp fuse in the circuit breaker before it got to the 25 amp fuse?

And would a 15 amp fuse in there actually limit the current to 15 amps before it even reaches the outlet?

Would the be any complications to such a series?

This is for educational only, I am trying to understand how it works exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your question, the 25 amp fuse wouldn't do anything because the 20 Amp fuse/breaker would blow/trip first assuming that the characteristics of both devices were the same. And yes, a 15 Amp fuse would limit the current to 15 Amps but remember these protection devises can take a certain amount of overload before operating.

When you think about it, it's just like plugging a power strip with a 15 Amp circuit breaker into an outlet that is protected by a 20 Amp circuit breaker in the main panel. If you overload the power strip, it's circuit breaker would/should trip before the outlet breaker trips.

Comment: Ok, that's what I expected regarding that part of it.

Comment: @diyuser  Remember, this is "educational only".  If you're going to try something, check back here with your plan.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on where in the world you are.
In the UK this would be done with a 'fused spur', interior or exterior spec, with or without flex outlet.

[image] [image] [image]

As regular wall sockets tend not to have inbuilt fuses, then if you are running a spur [as opposed to a ring] you drop a fused box in before, or instead of, the socket itself. The box is independently switched & fused. The fuse can be any Amperage you wish to be your maximum. It is not dependent on the rating back in the main circuit breaker, though it should be the same or lower, just as a precaution.

Comment: It's in the US.

Comment: Then you just need the US equivalent.

Comment: ok, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: Well, now armed with what it's called, go investigate.

Comment: I am not armed as since you spoke in UK terms, I didn't understand it, and you also did not give a yes or no.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know every county's terms for all possible electrical items. What is it you wanted a yes or no answer to? If it was 'can I do this?' then presumably an answer explaining how to do it automatically includes the implication the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would ever happen.  Due to UL rules, appliances fit for 15A circuits have 15A plugs on them (the familiar NEMA 5-15, you know the one).

[image]

20A sockets are double notched to allow both 15A and 20A plugs.  Further, 15A sockets are allowed on 20A circuits directly (as long as there are 2 or more sockets).

So a "15A" (read: 12A continuous) appliance would be built with a NEMA 5-15 plug, and it can be plugged into any of the sockets allowed on a 120V/20A circuit.

And as you can see, 240V isn't "special" in this regard, the same rules apply just with different shaped pins.